# How to customize the ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular5, customization, ngx-bootstrap

I want to customize the ngx-bootstrap datepicker popup. Basically I want to add link/button in the calendar showing date and on click of that date will get added to date picker field.

I couldn't find any way to customize the datepicker. I am using Angular 5 and ngx-bootstrap:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a custom component based on the original datepicker adding custom element to template making it look like an integrated element with some css :

[image]

First change the height of the datepicker popup :

```
::ng-deep.bs-datepicker {
  height: 350px;
}
```

Then add the custom element to the datepicker :

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="myDateValue">
    <div class="custom-content" *ngIf="dp.isOpen">
        <a (click)="customAction()">{{myDateValue | date:'short'}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With some css :

```
.custom-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1081;
  top: 390px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
}
```

[Here is a running stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51062003)

A better solution would be to have the possibility to pass a template to the datepicker, but ngx-bootstrap doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: @ibenjelloun why import both  `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
        DatepickerModule.forRoot()`?

Comment: @Winnemucca I removed the DatepickerModule import from the stackblitz.

Comment: Hi, do you know I can't reduce the width of the body? No matter what I try I can't make the calendar smaller https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7rxmuq-8qgxp1

Answer (score -3):

**Not Recommended**, **You should not change on node_modules' files**, **but to using the above mention ( ngx-bootstrap/datepicker)  library, I couldn't be able to overwrite the CSS so that I just changed on bs-datepicker.css to solve my problem.**

CSS file

```
      "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
```

open css file

```
     node_modules -> ngx-bootsrap -> datapicker -> bs-datepicker.css class
```

find the CSS class which you want to change using  " inspect elements " 
then  find the class into bs-datepicker.css and change, for example, I want to change the header color green to blue

```
    .theme-green .bs-datepicker-head {
      // background-color :#green;  
      background-color: #4498fb;

     }
```

I change the background color of the header

Comment: don't change something in node_modules ever: you need to overwrite it in a stylesheet with an higher priority.